# UITableViewCell not being de-selected when touching a new row

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have some code in my willDisplayCell that selects a given row/cell.. this works

```
-(void) willDisplayCell ...

....

if (somecodition) [cell setSelected] (dont remember the actual methodname)

....
```

This is what I want to accomplish

```
-(void) ... cellForRow... {

     if <condition> setPrivateClassVar = indexPath
}

-(void) someMethod {

   [myTableView reloadData];

   [myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:PrivateClassVar ....]

   // I expected the variable to be set in cellForRow method.
}
```

That works fine because it highlighted the correct row. but sometimes after the UITableView is fully displayed and I touch away on to a new row in the table; the current selected row/cell is still hightlighted, leaving two rows selected.  Is this a normal behavor?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik this is not the default behavior. Are you sure you do not have any code re-selecting the old row?

Comment: I guess my question would be.. is willDisplayCell a good place to put the logic of auto-selecting a row? or is there a better spot for it?  some told me to put it after [tableview reloadData] but I think that call is asyncorous.

Comment: put it after reloadData. It is not asynchronous. None of the UI methods are as far as I know. They are rendered in the main thread.

Comment: I'll try that again. but I thought the when willDisplayCell is called it will overwrite my selected cell causing it to be de-selected

Comment: Not if you tell the table view which cell is the selected one first

Comment: if I make a call to [tableview reloadData] will all the table event fire first?  I put two break points one after the callt o [tableview reloaddata] and one in cellForRowAt....  the one after the call to [tableview reloaddata] is hit first I expected cellForRwo method to stop at the break point

Comment: is there a flag I need to set to tell it not to execute asyncoronously?  I want to use the cellForRow method to figure out the IndexPath and store it for later use.

Comment: Are you calling the reloadData from the main thread or some other thread?

Comment: i call it within the same class MyViewControll.m

Comment: Ok, what if you set the selected row before you reload the data? Im sorry but it seems you have some other issue. I have not had this problem (and it is very basic behavior).

Comment: When you talk about different thread what are you talking about?  Are you asking if I have Class1.m and Class2.m, class1 instantiate class2 and then calls back to class1 to do an tableview update? would that all be on the same thread?

Comment: Yes. You would know if you would do things in another thread, because then you have to start one yourself.

Comment: I ended up using a work around with NSTimer but that doesnt seem correct.